# Installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, 16.04, dell, logitech

I am a new Ubuntu user.   I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 as a stand alone system.   I made a disk image of ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso on my Mac Air laptop.    I tried the CD on my Mac Air and it works.  I then inserted the CD into my Supermicro Superworkstation (SYS-7038A-I).  The workstation seems to be accessing the CD, but I get a black screen except for a scrolling message on my Dell U2715H monitor that says there is no Display Port cable, but in fact, a DP cable is installed.   My graphics card is a NVIDIA Quadro K620.  I am using a Logitech K800 wireless keyboard and a Logitech M510 wireless mouse. The workstation is connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I had some USB devices connected to the Dell U2715H monitor.   When I removed the extraneous USB devices, the monitor woke up.